# Required: GeneratedMessageV3.Builder<*>: how initialize com.google.type.Money with a value

Tags: java, kotlin, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

Context: I want design a proto file containing a currency field which will be used in gRPC service response. I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://blog.jdriven.com/2020/04/practical-protobuf-02-first-call/)

I get this error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
GeneratedMessageV3.Builder<*>!
Found:String
```

It clearly says I must use GeneratedMessageV3.Builder but I don't know how do it.

Here is the proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

    package com.mycomp.adapters.grpc.test;
    
    import "google/api/annotations.proto";
    import "google/type/money.proto";
    
    service TestService {
    
      rpc GetTest (GetTestRequest) returns (Test) {
      }
    }
    
    message GetTestRequest{
        string id_cliente = 1;
    }
    
    message Test {
      string id_cliente = 1;
      google.type.Money test_money = 2;
    }
```

How I implemented the service and my issue to initialize a very simple com.google.type.Money variable.

```
import com.google.type.Money
...other imports

@Singleton
class TestEndpoint() : TestServiceGrpcKt.TestServiceCoroutineImplBase() {

    override suspend fun getTest(request: GetTestRequest): Test {

        val test = Test.newBuilder()

        ...
        
        test.testMoney = Money("999.99") //*** certainly my mistake is here

        return test.build()
    }
```

In case it is relevant, here are the most important part of build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    
    implementation ("com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.0.0")
}
```

I understand the only dependency I need in order to use import "google/api/annotations.proto" in proto file and import com.google.type.Money in Kotlin is

```
com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret [the javadoc](http://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/type/Money.html) correctly, you cannot instantiate the `Money` class directly. Instead use something like:

```java
test.testMoney = Money.newBuilder()
    .setCurrencyCode("USD")
    .setUnits(999)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying the proposed code above I get: Cannot access '<init>': it is private in 'Builder'. And I guess "setUnits" method isn't really the value, right? Let's say I want 9 dollars and 99 cents. How should I build it?

Comment: Do you still get the `<init>` error with the `newBuilder()` call (I updated the answer)?
For $9.99, you should use `setUnits(9)`, and `setNanos(99 * 10000000)`.

Comment: The $1.75 example from the `setNanos` API might help you: https://googleapis.github.io/gax-php/0.36.0/Google/Type/Money.html#method_setNanos

Comment: Thanks. It is fixed. You have answered my question. Now I am getting an issue with BloomRPC when I try to import the proto file: Error while importing protos
no such Type or Enum 'google.type.Money'. If you have an extra trick to me regard testing the gRPC endpoint it will be worth